# Determine if a 2-variable Diophantine equation has a finite or infinite number of solutions

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

Do there exist an algorithm, which, given a polynomial $P(x,y)$ with integer coefficients, determines whether Diophantine equation $P(x,y)=0$ has finite or infinite number of integer solutions?

Famous 1929 Siegel's theorem states that the number of solutions is finite if the equation defines a smooth algebraic curve C of genus $g>0$. In a paper

DIMITRIOS POULAKIS AND EVAGGELOS VOSKOS Solving Genus Zero Diophantine Equations with at
Most Two Infinite Valuations J. Symbolic Computation (2002) 33, 479–491

the authors, assuming that $P(x,y)$ is absolutely irreducible, developed a necessary and sufficient condition for a curve of genus 0 to have infinitely many integer points.

If $P(x,y)$ is reducible over integers, the problem reduces to the same problem for each of the factors. However, there are polynomials irreducible over integers but not absolutely irreducible. Also, in the genus $g>0$ case, there are polynomials such that the corresponding curve is not smooth (has singular points), so that Siegel's theorem is not applicable.

Are there any results covering these cases? If not, do you know any explicit example of equation $P(x,y)=0$ for which it is open whether it has finite or infinite number of integer solutions?

Comment: The singular case is deduced from the non-singular case by means of the normalization/desingularization process,  at least if the genis is $>0$. The irreducible but not absolutely irreducible case should be not a problem, just changing base.

Comment: In fact, an irreducible polynomial in two variables that has infinitely many rational points is automatically absolute irreducible, since the set of rational points is then dense.

Comment: Thank you. From your comments it looks like this problem is decidable, and the proof is not difficult. It is then a bit surprising that I never met a paper or book where this result is formulated and accurately proved. Do you know any reference where I can read how to, for example, deduce the singular case from non-singular one?

Answer (score 4):

I now find that such an algorithm indeed exists. It is described, for example, in the introduction of paper

Yuri Bilu and Robert Tichy. The diophantine equation f (x) = g(y). Acta Arithmetica, 95:261–288, 2000.